# App store install process

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, app-store

Does anyone know how iOS installs apps after they are purchased

The reason I ask is that I am going to modify a CoreData model and the existing unversioned model .mom file conflicts with the .momd versioned folder in a not clean install process with the usual "'Can't merge models with two different entities named 'Foo'' issue if using mergedModel...

No problem if I discard the app and start again but a big problem for Joe User.

I cant delete the original .mom file programmatically as that hits perms problems

So the question is , is an App Store upgrade a clean operation or is it a delta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version of the application is completely downloaded.  Once it is finished, the user files that are identified by the iOS documentation as persistent are copied to the same location in the new copy of the app.  The old app is deleted and the application icon on the springboard will now launch the new version.

Comment: It doesn't launch the new app after the download is complete. Have you ever installed an app? :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer below is great but also a solution to the actual problem is here

[Core data migration failing with "Can't find model for source store" but managedObjectModel for source is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532115/core-data-migration-failing-with-cant-find-model-for-source-store-but-managedo)